# multiprocessing Event subclassing

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have attempted to subclass `Event` from `multiprocessing`, but it doesn't work, does anyone know why?

```
from multiprocessing import Event

class MyEvent(Event):
     def __init__(self):
         self.__init__()
```

I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Event` is actually a function that returns an instance of `multiprocessing.synchronize.Event`. You would need to subclass that class directly.

(Note also that your `__init__` method is very strange, and will cause an infinite recursion. I suspect you meant to call `super()`; but if you are not actually doing anything in that method, it is better not to define it at all.)